When can à + verb mean "in order to"?
When learning how to use à/de/pour with verbs (because all three can translate into English as "to verb"), I learned that I should use à + verb when the noun before it is being verb-ed, like C'est une chose à manger, pas à gâcher or Cette tâche est impossible à faire, otherwise, I should use de + verb in basically all other situations, like C'est impossible de faire cette tâche. Pour, on the other hand, is simply synonymous to afin de, and should translate to in order to.
This went well for me, until I saw instances where I think à + verb is being used to mean in order to verb. Namely, in a song called La Vaguelette(from Genshin Impact), there is a line:

Moi, je suis et serai toujours là, à voir le monde et sa beauté

I'm pretty sure it means I am and will always be there, (in order) to see the world and its beauty, yet I would have totally expected a pour instead of a à, because like I said above, XX à voir is XX to see as in XX for seeing, like C'est un livre à lire, pas à dessiner.
Could someone explain the usage of the à above ? Thanks !

When you say "the noun before it is being verb-ed" I understand you mean that the word is primarily used as a noun and can in this instance be used as a verb. That is not something we would say in French grammar. When we say c'est à manger,  manger is definitely a verb. Verb infinitives can sometimes be used as nouns, and not the opposite. But that is not the crux of your question, which is clear about the use of à before an infinitive.

In this sentence from La vaguelette pour could also be used but, personally, I can feel a difference. Pour could imply a voluntary gesture from the subject, something she purposely wants to do. Using à can mean she can't help it, she'll still be there, so she'll be able to see the world.
Être à followed by an infinitive can either mean:

an action is taking place: je suis là à t'attendre sous la pluie et toi tu n'as même pas encore mis tes chaussures
purpose or destination: cette maison est à vendre.

But be aware that lots of other verbs than être can be followed by à + infinitive. The way you put it is to my mind too simplistic. Pour, indeed, means "in order to" and knowing when to use pour is probably not too difficult. But knowing when to use de or à is not as simple as you seem to think since we can't always go by the meaning. With some verbs, both à or de can be used, and then the meaning may differ1, but for most verbs it is the one or the other. French natives know this by usage, for non natives lists can easily be found2 to help them to start with.

1 For example continuer à vs continuer de. Il a continué à rouler bien qu'il ait heurté un piéton. || Il a continué de conduire bien qu'on lui ait retiré son permis. 
2For example here. 

In là, à voir le monde, the preposition à doesn't mean 'in order to' (i.e. an intention) but concurrence:

I'll be there, seeing the world.

